# Custom action button enable/disable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I want to enable or disable custom Action button on following condition.

When user select list items in the list and if the user (created by) is particular user Group then I want to disable the Button.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Where is your custom action? In the Ribbon?  What have you tried so far?  Can you share the code you used to create your custom action / your custom action definition?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?  Is this SharePoint Online?

Comment: It's SharePoint 2016 on premise.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following javascript script

```
// The below checks if the user exists in the group
function CheckUser(groupID, isInThisGroup) {

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   //Go to parent site if use in a subsite!
    var siteColl = context.get_site();
    web = siteColl.get_rootWeb();
    var groupCollection = web.get_siteGroups();
    // Get the Group's ID
    var _group = groupCollection.getById(groupID); 
    // Get all Users of the group
    var users = _group.get_users();
    context.load(_group);
    context.load(users);
    this._users = users;
    // Get current user
    this._currentUser = web.get_currentUser(); 
    this._isInThisGroup = isInThisGroup;
    context.load(this._currentUser);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.CheckUserSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
}

//The below Checks if User is the member of the specified group
function CheckUserSucceeded() {

    if (this._users.get_count() > 0) {
        var _usersEnum = this._users.getEnumerator();
        while (_usersEnum.moveNext()) {
            var user = _usersEnum.get_current();
            if (user.get_loginName() == this._currentUser.get_loginName()) {
                //debugger;
                arrIsInThisGroup[this._isInThisGroup] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More information, please refer to this article:

- [Sharepoint 2010 - Enable/Disable Ribbon Button with EcmaScript](http://webdevshareetc.blogspot.com/2011/10/sharepoint-2010-enabledisable-ribbon.html)

Comment: you are being very presumptuous as to which version of SharePoint and which UX  *user1514428* is using in his/her environment.  Linking to a 10 year old article written about a now unsupported version of SharePoint which may not apply if he/she is ***not*** using the Classic UX - that is not helpful.  Give the user time to respond to the comments!  Your code will **not** work if he/she is using the Modern UX.  I would expect more from MSFT commenters.